# How does one splice together parts of two 3D density plots, without changing the original colors?

Tags: graphics3d, color, opacity

How does one splice together the t=0 to 59 part of the first plot with the t=59 to 60 part of the second plot, without changing the original colors of either plot? I have spent hours looking for an answer.

```
f[x_, y_, 
   t_] = (E^(-((-10 + x)^2/(4 + 2 I t)) - (10 + y)^2/(4 + 
           2 I t)) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]])/(2 + I t);
g[x_, y_, 
   t_] = (E^(-(x^2/(4 + 2 I (60 - t))) - y^2/(4 + 2 I (60 - t))) Sqrt[
      2/\[Pi]])/(2 + I (60 - t));
DensityPlot3D[Re[f[x, y, t]], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 0, 60}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}]
DensityPlot3D[Re[g[x, y, t]], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 0, 60}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `Piecewise` is all what you need:

```
f2[x_, y_, t_] = 
 Piecewise[{{Re[f[x, y, t]], 0 <= t < 59}, {Re[g[x, y, t]], 59 <= t <= 60}}]
DensityPlot3D[f2[x, y, t], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 0, 60}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}]
```

**Note**: as [C. E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) correctly notes in the comments, this solution works only for the cases when resulting `Piecewise` function has the same range of values in the given domain as both the original functions. If not, the coloring will change due to the default `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` option. To workaround this one should set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` for all three plots and define appropriate custom `ColorFunction` for them. The latter usually (depending on the behavior of the objective functions and user's goals) should cover the whole range of values of the original objective functions in the given domain. Of course, all these complications are necessary only if the original two plots are to be demonstrated alongside with the third plot, and hence all three plots must have the same color scale (i.e. any given color must correpond to the same value in all plots).

**Note 2**: as [C. E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) explains in the comments, his understanding of the situation is opposite to mine. I assume that all three plots must have the same color scale, while his understanding is that two original plots may have different color scales and should be combined into one plot keeping original colors (what leads to confusing sutuation, because in different parts of the resulting plot any given color may correspond to different values of the functions). Both interpretations are valid given the original formulation of the question, and in the specific case presented in OP seemingly lead to the same resulting plot. But one should note that these two approaches are entirely different and will lead to different results in the general case.

---

Here I use other ranges for the `Piecewise` just to demonstrate that the colors are really preserved:

```
f[x_, y_, t_] = (E^(-((-10 + x)^2/(4 + 2 I t)) - (10 + y)^2/(4 + 2 I t)) Sqrt[
      2/\[Pi]])/(2 + I t);
g[x_, y_, t_] = (E^(-(x^2/(4 + 2 I (60 - t))) - y^2/(4 + 2 I (60 - t))) Sqrt[
      2/\[Pi]])/(2 + I (60 - t));
f2[x_, y_, t_] = 
  Piecewise[{{Re[f[x, y, t]], 0 <= t < 30}, {Re[g[x, y, t]], 30 <= t <= 60}}];
p1 = DensityPlot3D[Re[f[x, y, t]], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 0, 60}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}, ImageSize -> 300];
p2 = DensityPlot3D[Re[g[x, y, t]], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 0, 60}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}, ImageSize -> 300];
p3 = DensityPlot3D[f2[x, y, t], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 0, 60}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{p1, p2, p3}]
```

> [image: output]

Comment: Since `ColorFunctionScaling` is `True`, all function values are scaled by the minimum and maximum function values. If you draw both functions with the same call to `DensityPlot3D` then the maximum/minimum will not be computed for each function separately, and therefore the colors will change.

Comment: @C.E. I hadn't checked this, but it looks like maximum and minimum are the same, because my solution really preserves original colors without playing with `ColorFunction`.

Comment: @C.E. I added the comparison section with rendered plots as a proof.

Comment: ok, but then I think that it at least warrants a comment in the answer because people reading this in the future may not realize that it only works for this special case. My solution works for any functions.

Comment: @C.E. Added the comment. Thanks.

Comment: The maximum and minimum are the same.

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney Just be aware that if you are going to use another function in the future where the maximum and minimum are not the same, then it will not be as simple as turning off `ColorFunctionScaling`. Color functions expect values between 0 and 1, so if your functions values are, say, between 2 and 10, then the plots would have a uniform color. You would have to do your own scaling. In order to preserve the colors, that would involve computing the maximum and minimum values of each of the functions in the given domain separately.

Comment: @C.E. As I see it, the problem should be solved by defining only one `ColorFunction` for all three plots, which usually (depending on the behavior of the function and the user's goals) should cover the whole range of values of objective functions in the first two plots. But strictly speaking, the last requirement isn't necessary: coloring will be identical even if the function covers only the range of values of the `Piecewise` function.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov My understanding of the question is that two different plots use the same color function, but the values in the different plots should be mapped differently to the color function. This solution does not solve that problem, except incidentally in the special case presented in this answer. My understanding is that we do not have the situation that you describe in your comment.

Comment: @C.E. Yes, your understanding of the situation is opposite to mine. Both interpretations are possible since the OP didn't give enough details. Also in the specific case of the OP both solutions produce what the OP want.

Answer (score 5):

Just using `Show` should do it:

```
dp1 = DensityPlot3D[
   Re[f[x, y, t]],
   {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 0, 30},
   ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors",
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}
   ];
dp2 = DensityPlot3D[
   Re[g[x, y, t]],
   {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 30, 60},
   ColorFunction -> "SolarColors",
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}
   ];

Show[
 dp1,
 dp2,
 PlotRange -> {{-60, 60}, {-60, 60}, {0, 60}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Actually the colors are different as compared with the original plots.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I looked at them now again and I can't see that they are different. Maybe you didn't notice that I picked new color schemes for the plots just to show more clearly that the colors are preserved.

Comment: Well, now I see that you understood the requirement of the OP in a completely different way than I did. From a purely formal point of view, your interpretation is also correct. But I don’t think the OP meant exactly that.

Comment: I did not mean exactly that, but changing both AlpineColors and SolarColors to Rainbow gives the result I wanted.

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney Of course, again, I only changed the color schemes to make it obvious that the colors are preserved.

Comment: It is woth to note that this solution (if we use one `ColorFunction` for both original plots) has even more serious limitation than mine: it will work only if objective functions has the same range of values in the given (partial) domains. So it is even more fragile than mine. The workaround is the same, of course: set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` for both plots and define appropriate custom `ColorFunction` for them.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't understand what you mean. If you have a plot A that you are satisfied with, and a plot B that you are satisfied with, and you want to put them together, then `Show` does exactly that. This is my understanding of the question, and there is no problem with this approach from that point of view. It has nothing to do with `ColorFunctionScaling`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Let's consider the case where both plots have the same color schemes but different ranges of values. A given color, let's say (1, 0, 0), will not to correspond to the same value in the two plots, because of the scaling. This is confusing when they are put into the same plot, sure, but it is also exactly what I think that OP would want given his question.  He wants, as he says, to put them together "without changing the original colors of either plot".

Comment: @C.E. Here we are different: I assumed that OP wish to avoid such confusing situation completely, i.e. any given color must correpond to the same value in all plots.